# Dual Variable Solutions from Primal in Cplex

Tags: c++, cplex, primality-test

I am coding cplex concert technology in C++. When I solve primal problem (with primal simplex, dual simplex or interior point, method is not important), can I extract solution values, such as extreme ray values of dual variables if dual problem is unbounded, or optimal solution values of dual variables if dual problem has optimal solution?

Comment: I am sorry if I wrote sth inappropriate but I couldn't understand, is there a possible way to do this?

Comment: Have you already tried `isPrimalFeasible` and `isDualFeasible`, and followed it up with `getDuals`? Could you be a little more specific on what you are looking for beyond that?